# Python read EEG data form .csv file using mne?

Tags: python

I want to use Python `mne` library. I have a `.csv` file with `EEG data`. The first column is `Time (ms)` and the next 16 columns are `EEG data` for 16 channels. Sampling rate is 2048Hz. I want to use `mne` to analyse data. Have tried mne.io.RawArray but get the error: `ValueError: len(data) does not match len(info["ch_names"])`. What should I do?

Code I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import mne

path = 'my path'
data = pd.read_csv(path + 'file.csv', 
                   skiprows=0, usecols=[*range(0, 17)]) 
ch_names = ['CH 1', 'CH 2', 'CH 3', 'CH 4', 'CH 5', 'CH 6', 'CH 7', 'CH 8', 'CH 9',
            'CH 10', 'CH 11', 'CH 12', 'CH 13', 'CH 14', 'CH 15', 'CH 16']

sfreq = 2048 
info = mne.create_info(ch_names = ch_names, sfreq = sfreq)
raw = mne.io.RawArray(data, info)
raw.plot()
```

Sample data screenshot attached. Please note there is another column "Channel 16" not shown. [EEG sample data 16 channels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPXUg.png)

Comment: Can you post sample data in the question?

Comment: please check edited post

Comment: Can you please post text of the sample data instead of a screenshot? That way, users can copy and paste the data easily, and you will be more likely to get a response to your question.

Comment: what's the best way of doing so? Cant see any option to upload a .csv sample

Answer (score 1):

Your data frame has channels as columns. But,

```
raw = mne.io.RawArray(data, info)
```

This expects channels as rows.
Try passing `data.transpose()`